Identity matrix in Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm for overdetermined system of equations
I'm trying to learn using LM algorithms for solving non-linear equation system.
The trail step of LM algorithm is:
$$ x_{k+1} = x_{k}-\ (J_{k}^{\ T} J_{k} + \lambda_k  I)^{\ -1} \ J_{k}^{\ T}\ F_{k}  $$
However, when the system is overdetermined (m≠n), we can't calculate the identity matrix $ I$ directly. Can we use the pseudo-inverse to calculate $J_{k}^{\dagger} J_{k} $ and substitute $ I$ ?

$J$ may be rectangular, but $J^TJ$ is a square matrix so you can add $\lambda I$ to it without encountering any dimensional issues.
